# AWS Data Pipeline Schedule to run Monday to Friday

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm using AWS Data Pipeline to shut down my EC2 servers on a daily basis as described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/stop-start-ec2-instances/) but I would like to start them up only during the working week which is Monday to Friday. The schedules in Data Pipelines seem to be quite basic so does anyone know if there is any way to execute an AWS Data Pipeline only Monday to Friday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not supported by data pipeline currently. You might have to create 5 different pipelines (one for each day) as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the Pipeline and choosing Build using a template > Run AWS CLI Command you're allowed to use unix commands in the AWS CLI Command field. Once I figured that out I was able to put

```
test $(date +"%u") -lt 6 &&
```

in front of the aws command which essentially prevents the aws cli command from running on weekends. Final entry in that field looks like:

```
test $(date +"%u") -lt 6 && aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-12345678 --region us-east-1
```

It's not perfect as the pipeline activation still counts for pipeline billing purposes, but it does prevent unnecessary ec2 billing for running an instance over the weekend.